# No FB access token upon initial Parse FB login

Tags: facebook, swift, parse-platform, token

I am logging into my app using `PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions` however, the first time I log in the actual login works fine but I get the FB error `code = 2500 An active access token must be used to query information about the current user`. This results in any graphRequests failing.

If I then recompile the code to the device this error does not occur and all graphRequests work fine. Why is the app not getting an access token upon the first login? Also, if I completely delete the app from the device and reinstall this whole process starts again (error code = 2500 on first attempt).

Also maybe worth noting, this didn't happen with the previous versions of Parse and FB SDKs. I am just starting to move this app into iOS9 and that's when this problem popped up.

Xcode 7.0.1, Parse SDK v1.8.5, FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150910

Comment: I also found that I can work around this event by killing the app (and by killing i mean double tap home + swipe up) and relaunching. For some reason, the next time the app is launched the access token exists.

Comment: I've also tried running `FBSDKAccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessToken` in the hopes it would DL a new token but this results in a similar error message being returned ("no access token exists")

Comment: please update your question with some more details of your code. Show us the code.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by first calling the FBSDK login method followed by the Parse SDK login method (inside the FBSDK callback):

```
@IBAction func facebookButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Ensure that PFUser == nil - just in here because I heard it can help with some possible issues
    PFUser.logOut()

    let permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]

    // First, login with FB’s SDK
    let login: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    login.logInWithReadPermissions(permissions, handler: {(result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) in

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog("Process error")
        } else {
            if result.isCancelled {
                NSLog("Cancelled")
            } else {
                NSLog("Logged in")

                // Then with Parse’s, upon FB login success
                PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions) { (user, error) -> Void in

                    if let user = user {
                        if user.isNew {
                            print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!”)
                            //... 
                        } else {
                            print("User logged in through Facebook!")
                            //... 
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
                        //... 
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    })
}
```